# Unable to do db index from python django

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, django-models, indexing

I tried to indexing my db from python django model class. But while doing migrate it throw error like this.
psycopg2.errors.ReadOnlySqlTransaction: cannot execute CREATE EXTENSION in a read-only transaction

Please help to resolve this issue. Is it because of any access problem. My db is in azure. I am able to read and write data to the db.

Comment: It appears that your database connection... is read-only...